# Modifying the schema of a table to make it inherit from another one without recreating the table or reinserting the data

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I have several tables in my PostgreSQL database that have a couple of common columns. I thought it would be a good idea if I move those common columns into a new table and made the tables inherit from this new table. For example:

```
create table foo_bar (
    code varchar(9) primary key,
    name varchar,
    bar integer
);
```

After refactoring:

```
create table foo (
    code varchar(9) primary key,
    name varchar
);

create table foo_bar (
    bar integer
) inherits (foo);
```

The problem is, I have lots of data in `foo_bar`, as well as many views that refer to this table.

Is it possible to alter definition of `foo_bar` to achieve the above change without dropping the data in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    code varchar(9),
    name varchar
);

ALTER TABLE foo_bar INHERIT foo;
```

Comment: Ha! I didn't think it would be that easy. I tested it and it works. The only weird thing is that now if I dump the database it explicitly shows the inherited columns in the definition of `foo_bar`. I shouldn't see them. But they are really inherited, if I try to drop those columns from `foo_bar` I get an error saying that I can't cause they're inherited. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It may or may not be a good idea. Database design isn't exactly object oriented programming. There are some [caveats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-inherit.html).

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes
>   (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply
>   to single tables, not to their inheritance children. This is true on
>   both the referencing and referenced sides of a foreign key constraint.

And there are few more issues described at that link which you need to be aware of.

If you really want to go ahead with this, how to alter the table is given in Laurenz Albe's answer.

Comment: Thanks. In my my case the caveats are not a problem and the fact that I can select the base table and have PostgreSQL select automatically all "child" tables is very useful.